# How can I efficiently cache/index an aggregate subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Essentially I have a schema that includes the following:

```
thread
   id (uuid)
   ...

message
   id (uuid)
   thread (uuid)
   time (timestamptz)
   (thread) -> thread(id)
   ...
```

I frequently need to query for `thread`s based on when the most recent message was sent within them (among other conditions).

I have indexed `message` by `(thread, time)` which helped initially, but as the number of `thread`s increased it became clear that I needed to be able to directly index `thread` by `last_message_time`.

I can of course store this in a separate denormalized field, perhaps with assistance from triggers, but ideally I'd like avoid denormalization and guarantee that the field is in sync.

As far as I can tell check constraints and generated columns cannot involve subqueries, so I was hoping for advice on how to best achieve this.

It seems as though this isn't all that fundamentally different from a foreign key, particularly given the `(thread, time)` index that can be re-used, however it seems like PostgreSQL may not currently be expressive enough to do this in a nice way.

Comment: Edit your question and show the query that you are using.

Comment: How many messages could be for single thread? 100? 1000? Indexing of 1000 rows is usually inefficient.

Comment: If you don't want to denormalize, then you should see if you can make the query faster without denormalization.  To do that, you should show us the query and the execution plan for it.

Answer (score -1):

An index on `message(thread, time desc)` should be optimal for a query such as:

```
select distinct on (thread) m.*
from message m
order by thread, time desc;
```

I can't think of a faster way of running a query to get the most recent message for each thread.

Comment: No. Index like `message(thread, time desc)` increases its size at least two times compared to `message(thread)` index. Additionally, having in mind the recent changes in `btree` indexes in the PostgreSQL 13 such index could be huger for a lot.

Comment: @Abelisto . . . I have no idea what your comment is referring to.  The OP already claims to have an index on `message(thread, time)`, not on `message(thread)`.  And space considerations are not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Index on `field1` have the size (filed1 data type + ctid) and index on `field1, field2` have the size (field1 + field2 + `ctid`) Taking in account that values aligned to 4 bytes, the second index could be 3-4 times larger (3-4 times slower) Short: size (if yo have no ideas unfortunately)

Comment: According to 1017k of your exp it seems that you have no any exp about real (physical, more then 1 TB) DB (it is strange for me, sorry)

Comment: @GordonLinoff The issue is that there are a ton of threads, most of them inaccessible to any given person, so this still takes too long to get the top ~30 threads that matter. I will edit the OP soon to add more details. Storage space is not a significant concern unless it's somehow leading to slower queries.